# How do I do VLOOKUP in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
df1 has a commodity code column and I want class from a mapping file. The mapping file has a commodity code along with class column. So essentially, I want class column in my df1 from df2. I had done this using VLOOKUP in excel and merge function in Pandas but all I am getting are NaN's which are wrong.
Code I used: `print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Commodity', how='left'))`

```
df1 
Commodity
UN101
UN102

df2
Commodity Class
UN101     A
UN102     B
```

Expected Output:

```
df1
Commodity Class
UN101     A
UN102     B

Few points: 
1. in df2, 1 class name can have multiple commodity code. 

Sample Wrong Result:
Commodity Class
UN101     NaN
UN102     NaN
```

Comment: Can you add some row with exist in both DataFrames and wrongly added `NaN` ?

Comment: Also are both columns same type, e.g. string? If not, try `df1['Commodity'] = df1['Commodity'].astype(str)` and `df2['Commodity'] = df2['Commodity'].astype(str)` before merge

Comment: Yes, Both are string. I have done this conversion. Adding Sample Nan.

Comment: Also possible trailing spaces? Try `df1['Commodity'] = df1['Commodity'].str.strip() and df2['Commodity'] = df2['Commodity'].str.strip()`

Comment: Amazing. This worked! How did I miss this? Thanks :)